# Including linux command in C++ program

Tags: c++, linux

I intend to include a linux command in C++ program. I have been using the system() function to achieve the effect, like to print the current directory I've been using system("pwd"), for system calls and signals realted to 'ls' I used system("strace ls"), but now I want to use the strace command such that the user should type in the command(like ls,mv,who etc.) or process for which he wants to strace without hard-coding.

Comment: What is your question?  How to prompt for user input?

Comment: `system("cd")` does not "print the current directory".

Comment: @ashutosh -- I assume you are aware of the security implications and risk you will have by taking user input and executing it using `system` (or `popen`)?  This is generally a bad idea unless you 100% trust the users providing the input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For shell [builtins](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html) like `cd` or `ulimit` (etc...) it is useless to use them in the argument of [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) since it will only affect the `/bin/sh` process started by `system`.
You need to use the relevant [syscall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) in your C program, e.g. call [chdir(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chdir.2.html) or [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html)

<sup>It may have some sense to do `system("cd /tmp; gzip a*");` for example.</sup>

The list of system calls is in [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html). Read also [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)

BTW, most commands are giving some output (at least if asked by a suitable program argument). You may want to use [popen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) with `pclose` ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `system()` system call for for executing the linux commands. You can even use `execl` variants for executing the linux commands by replacing the a process address space.